# How to automatically update SQLite database after specific period in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, greendao

In my app I need to update  a specific column in table after specific time. My app runs completely offline it doesn't required any network connection like wifi even a sim card . I am using greedDao orm in my app . Is there any way to accomplish this ?

Comment: What kind of update? Why can't it be deferred until your app is reopened?

Comment: As an example when user will first install the app , a database will be created . And there will be table name "User" . In User table there is a column "is_active" , when user will first installed the app  the value of that column will be "1" but after 1 month I want to make it "0"

Comment: And why can't you defer this until the user re-opens the app? Until then, nobody is reading the DB anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using a job scheduler to schedule periodic jobs in your application.

Try the below article to learn about job scheduler.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-jobscheduler-api-on-android-lollipop--cms-23562

Answer (score 1):

You have two option to do this

1. By Scheduling Repeating Alarms https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html
2. Or use TimerTask http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html